# storing a 'pointer' to parts of a JSON tree in a PySide tableview

Tags: python, json, pyside

I have some data that is represented by heavily nested JSON, which I parse and populate a UI with in Python (specifically PySide).

My UI is essentially two panes, on the left is a table view with the flattened tree, and on the right will be the tree view. Clicking on a cell in the table view should repopulate the tree view on the right.

The problem I have is, how do I set a pointer in the table view's model to the corresponding entry in the JSON data? (i.e. how can I get an entry in my flat list to point to the right spot in my JSON data?)

I thought of using the trick from the old MFC days in Win32, wherein you set arbitrary item data for UI, but looking at the Qt table view class, their item data function seems to be doing something different.

Any thoughts?

Thank you for your time...

Answer (score 0):

Serialize the navigation to the value as a representation, and parse it when you want to access the item. E.g.:

```
foo.1->bar -> data['foo'][1]['bar']
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your data is shared across views, having a single model makes more sense. Make your main model a tree model. Then you can write a proxy model (subclassed from [`QAbstractProxyModel`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractproxymodel.html)) that flattens this tree model for your `QTableView`. You can now easily get the 'pointer' to main tree model.

If you want to show only parts of your tree model, you can use [`setRootIndex`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtreeview.html#setRootIndex) of `QTreeView`.